# How to remove unwanted space after HTML textarea

Tags: html, css, textarea

I am trying to remove some unwanted spacing that exists after a textarea.
In this example (in Chrome) a small space exists after the textarea and none after the input.
In Firefox I can see spacing after both.
It doesn't seem to be linked to border css.
I have tried several outline options.
Anyone have a solution?

```css
.it{
  min-width: 100%;
  border: none;
  background-color: lightblue;
  outline: none;
}
.it:focus{
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
<input class="it"/>
<textarea class="it"/></textarea>
<input class="it"/>
<textarea class="it"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: display: block to textarea

Answer (score -1):

I think you can put specific height to textareas and user can expand it they want. `margin: 0;` removes a little bit of margins but not all of them.

```css
.it{
  min-width: 100%;
  border: none;
  background-color: lightblue;
  outline: none;
}
.it:focus{
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}

.specific-height {
  height: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<input class="it"/>
<textarea class="it"/></textarea>
<input class="it"/>
<textarea class="it specific-height"></textarea>
</div>
```